# Creating XML Using Oracle XMLgen Utility Using In Memory Table Data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using `dbms.xmlgen` utility in Oracle to create XML document from the data saved to oracle memory table .

My procedure is saving the data in Oracle type `ITEM_ARRAY`. This is table of `ITEM_OBJECT` type.

Finally data is there in my `ITEM_ARRAY`. Now I want to convert this data into XML. So I am using following code

```
ctx:= DBMS_XMLGEN.newContext(' SELECT *  FROM TABLE(CAST(V_ITEMLIST AS ITEM_ARRAY))  where (ITEM_NO is not null or trim(ITEM_NO) is not null) order by ITEM_NO,PARTYABBRVCODE ');
DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowTag (ctx, 'itembom');
DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowSetTag (ctx, 'itemboms');
xmldoc := DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(ctx);
```

My this code is returning error that `V_ITEMLIST` does not exist.

But when I am doing dbms_out like

```
For I In 1..V_Itemlist.Count Loop
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Partyabbrvcode '||V_Itemlist(I).Partyabbrvcode);
DBms_Output.Put_Line('Item_No'||V_Itemlist(I).Item_No);
```

This is returning values.

I was trying different method like saving `V_ITEMLIST`  into cursor then calling this code as below.

```
ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext (ITEMCUR);
xmldoc := DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(ctx);
DBMS_XMLGEN.closeContext(ctx);
```

where item cursor is

```
SELECT *  FROM TABLE(CAST(V_ITEMLIST AS ITEM_ARRAY))  where (ITEM_NO is not null or trim(ITEM_NO) is not null) order by ITEM_NO,PARTYABBRVCODE.
```

This is also showing error numeric or value error.

Anybody please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Serveral lines of codes don't use any sort of quotes for formatting, just indenting. Just insert the code, select it and click the `{ }` button. And using all uppercase is considered bad style. I've fixed both.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_XMLGEN.newContext executes a SQL query, but SQL cannot directly access PL/SQL data.  The query must call a function that returns the relevant data.

```
SQL> set long 1000
SQL>
SQL> create or replace package xml_package as
  2     type varchar2_table is table of varchar2(100);
  3     function get_items return varchar2_table pipelined;
  4     function get_xml return clob;
  5  end;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace package body xml_package as
  2     g_items varchar2_table := varchar2_table();
  3
  4     function get_items return varchar2_table pipelined is
  5     begin
  6             for i in 1 .. g_items.count loop
  7                     pipe row(g_items(i));
  8             end loop;
  9     end;
 10
 11     function get_xml return clob is
 12             v_xml clob;
 13             v_context number;
 14     begin
 15             g_items := varchar2_table('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
 16             v_context := dbms_xmlgen.newContext(
 17                     'select * from table(xml_package.get_items)');
 18             v_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getXML(v_context);
 19             return v_xml;
 20     end;
 21  end;
 22  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL> select xml_package.get_xml from dual;

GET_XML
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN_VALUE>item1</COLUMN_VALUE>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN_VALUE>item2</COLUMN_VALUE>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN_VALUE>item3</COLUMN_VALUE>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```